# use iterator ptr to update vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, eclipse-cdt

Code as follows:

```
#include "MyObject.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class MyCollection {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject*>> collection;
public:
    MyCollection();
    virtual ~MyCollection();

    int insert(MyObject* newValue);

};

int MyCollection::insert(MyObject* newValue) {
    if (collection.empty()) {
        collection.push_back(move(make_unique<MyObject*>(newValue)));
        return 0;
    }
    int index = collection.size()-1;

    collection.resize(collection.size()+1);
    vector<unique_ptr<MyObject*>>::reverse_iterator pos = collection.rbegin();

    for ( ; (index >= 0) && (pos+1) != collection.rend() && stringToUpper((*(pos+1)->get())->getObjectName()) > stringToUpper(newValue->getObjectName()); ++pos) {
        pos = (pos+1);
        index--;
    }

    pos = ?newValue; // How do I do this?
        //pos->reset(move(make_unique<MyObject*>(newValue)));

    return index+1;
}
```

make_unique() implementation taken from http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/37576903218/cpp11style-no-new-delete

My question is there a way to do what I'm attempting with the assignment to the reverse_iterator (pos = newValue)? One of my pitiful attempts is shown in the commented code.

Thanks!

Comment: Why `std::unique_ptr<MyObject*>`?  You need unique pointers to pointers, but the contained `MyObject*` pointers are not in danger of dangling or leaking?

Comment: You probably want to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> collection;`, what you have right now is a `vector` of `MyObject**` (ignoring the `unique_ptr`). Chances are you don't even need the `unique_ptr` at all, and the data member should just be `vector<MyObject>`, especially if you decided to use pointers in the name of *performance*.

Comment: MyObject is an abstract class and the vector is meant to contain a mixture of derived types. Changing to the non-pointer version as you suggest results in the above code like
    if (collection.empty()) {
     collection.push_back(move(make_unique<SimSolverObject>(newValue)));
        return 0;
    } which is illegal. I'm guessing my assumption about how this should work is faulty. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: would I be better off making this a     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>> collection;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as others have pointed out, you want a `vector<unique_ptr<MyObject>>` not `vector<unique_ptr<MyObject*>>`. It is fine to have a `unique_ptr` containing an abstract class (make sure the base class has a virtual destructor). You can implicitly cast from a `unique_ptr` containing a derived class.

Ideally I think `MyCollection::insert` should take a `unique_ptr` not a raw pointer so that the calling code creates objects using `make_unique` in the first place but let's leave it like it is for now.

I think you have a bit of confusion with `make_unique`. `make_unique` is designed to create an object and wrap it in a `unique_ptr` in one go, safely. Your `MyCollection::insert` doesn't really need to use `make_unique` because the object is already created. `unique_ptr` has a constructor that takes a raw pointer so you can create one directly from the raw pointer.

You can then push the `unique_ptr` onto the collection or replace `unique_ptr`s in the collection with new `unique_ptr`s fine:

```
class MyObject {
  public:
    virtual ~MyObject() = 0
};
MyObject::~MyObject() {}

class SimSolverObject : public MyObject {
};

class MyCollection {
  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> collection;
  public:
    void insert(MyObject* newValue);
};

void MyCollection::insert(MyObject* newValue) {
  //...

  // if we want to add to the collection
    collection.push_back(std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(newValue));

  // if we want to replace at iterator pos in collection
    *pos = std::unique_ptr<MyObject>(newValue);
}

// calling code
MyCollection mc;
MyObject* newValue = new SimSolverObject();
mc.insert(newValue)
```

If you do decide to change `MyCollection::insert` to take a `unique_ptr` it would look something like this:

```
void MyCollection::insert(std::unique_ptr<MyObject> newValue) {
  //... 

  // if we want to add to the collection
  collection.push_back(std::move(newValue));

  // if we want to replace at pos 
  *pos = std::move(newValue);
}
```

**Edit:** Your `for` loop looks a bit suspicious. I am not quite sure what you are trying to do but are you sure you want to increment the iterator twice? Once in the body of the for and once in the loop expression? I suspect the iterator is skipping over your condition and going out of bounds of the vector. When it hits the index condition you may be left with an invalid iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It compiles but has a problem at the line     *pos = unique_ptr<MyObject>(newValue);
where it seems to choke on deleting the object occupying *pos. Do I need to specify a deletor when constructing the unique_ptr?

Comment: @user3461317. Hmm... shouldn't need to define a custom deletor. Here is my test program: http://ideone.com/54F390 seems to compile and run ok...

Comment: Have added an edit to my answer with my suspicions on what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Chris! That was the problem. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. - Drew (my name, not yours) :-)